# Bash how to create a txt file of all file names in a directory

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am sure there is a simple answer but I have been struggling to create a txt file of all the file names in a directory.

I am currently in the directory of where I need to collect all the file names of. This is what I have tried.

```
for i in ls; $i |../log.txt ; done
```

The `log.txt` file exists in the directory above.

Comment: Just use `ls > ../log.txt`, no need for a loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Too much work.

```
ls > ../log.txt
```

Comment: Though for anything beyond trivial, see also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Answer (score 1):

This will exclude the directories from the list, leaving only the files.

```
ls -p | grep -v / > log.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this in case you would like to use a for:

```
for i in *; do echo $i >> /tmp/log.txt; done
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this 
`ls >> ../log.txt` 
to append to an existing file.
If you only use '>' the file will be truncated.

Answer (score 0):

simply run `ls * > log.txt` in your terminal.

Comment: The wildcard `*` does nothing useful here, and potentially causes problems (without `-d` it will descend into directories).  http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs explains a number of additional failure scenarios.